# Backbone Collection Fetch() doesnt work

Tags: collections, backbone.js, fetch

I have a jquery mobile based implementation of a mobile website and now learning backbone.js and rethinking the app to better organize it.

```
var membership = Backbone.Model.extend();

var memberships = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: membership,
    parse: function (resp, xhr) {
        },
    url: "/groups.svc/memberships/azxcv01"
    });

    var col1 = new memberships();
    col1.fetch({ success: function () {
        console.log(col1);
    }
});
```

In chrome, I see that the URL is formatted well and returns valid JSON back. The *parse()* event also gets a valid *resp*. But the *console.log()* above displays and empty array "[ ]".

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

try this,
here link to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w7xeb/  (updated)

```
var membership = Backbone.Model.extend();

var memberships = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: membership,
     parse: function (resp, xhr) {
           return resp;
       },
    });

    var col1 = new memberships();
    col1.fetch({ 
        url : "/restful/fortune",                 
        success: function () {
            console.log(col1);
    }
});
​
```

response

```
$.mockjax({
    url: "/restful/fortune",
    responseTime: 750,
    contentType: "text/json",
    responseText: [{
          a:'a'
      },{
          a:'b'
      },{
          a:'c'
      }]
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still see the same. the response for both col1 and resp are identical in the console (models: Array[0]).

Comment: Thanks, that gave me some good learning. But I was to solve the issue by making the parse() look like this

    parse: function (resp, xhr) {
        return JSON.parse(resp);
        },

Comment: you must have  return parsed response to parse function

Comment: yes, my response was in string format and was enclosed in " ".